# jQuery: check if column contains TD with certain class

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, each

I am using the following lines to create an array of all TDs matching a certain search term. If a TD contains my search term then it has the class "`highlight`" added.

The below works fine so far my only problem is that I need to add 0 if one column does not contain my search term (a column either has the value or not but it cannot appear more than once in the same column).

The columns in question are columns `2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12` so my array should always contain 6 values and just show 0 if one of these columns does not contain the search term.

In other words: I need to check whether a column contains a TD with the class "highlight" or not.

**My function:**

```
var arr = new Array();
$('.highlight').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).text());
});
```

**Example HTML:**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th class="mayContainHighlight"></th>
            <th></th>
            <th class="mayContainHighlight"></th>
            <th></th>
            <th class="mayContainHighlight"></th>
            <th></th>
            <th class="mayContainHighlight"></th>
            <th></th>
            <th class="mayContainHighlight"></th>
            <th></th>
            <th class="mayContainHighlight"></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="mayContainSearchTerm highlight">search term</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td class="mayContainSearchTerm highlight">search term</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td class="mayContainSearchTerm highlight">search term</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td class="mayContainSearchTerm">other data</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td class="mayContainSearchTerm highlight">search term</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td class="mayContainSearchTerm">other data</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        // more TRs...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope someone can help me with this. Many thanks in advance, Tim.

Comment: Wheres the search term?

Comment: If you could add a fiddle, that would be very helpful :)

Comment: @tymeJV: Thanks. The search term is not relevant as all TDs matching this have the class "highlight". I need to go by the columns I listed and then check whether they contain a TD with the class "highlight". If yes, then add it to the array, if not then add 0 instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i have understand what do you mean and you don't have any other TD in the page ( if you have you need to identify the ones you want select)

you can edit you cod with this:

```
var arr = new Array();
$('TD').each(function() {
  if( $(this).hasClass("highlight") )
    arr.push($(this).text());
  else
    arr.push("0");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to go by the columns I listed and then check whether they contain a TD with the class "highlight". If yes, then add it to the array, if not then add 0 instead.

Comment: I found out that adding a class to refer to specific TDs only works in combination with the above. Thanks a lot to MackieeE for all the help on understanding this !

Answer (score 1):

By using an object, you can use a `key: value` storage, which is what I think you're requiring for knowing which columns have what value, for which they default to `0` if unmatched. Furthermore, the `.each()` loop itself is filtered by selecting only of those with `highlight` attached:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-column="2">Column2 </td>
        <td data-column="4">4th Column</td>
        <td data-column="6">Sixth Test</td>
        <td data-column="8">8More</td>
        <td data-column="10">10th Col</td>
        <td class="highlight" data-column="12">last Col</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    var obj = {
        2:  0,
        4:  0,
        6:  0,
        8:  0,
        10: 0,
        12: 0
    };

    $('td.highlight').each(function (index, element) {
        obj[$(element).data('column')] = $(this).text();
    });

    //Prints 'last Col'
    console.log( obj[12] );
</script>
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fZDYv/

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't think this is what I need. I need to check if one of the above columns contains a TD with the class "highlight". In this case add the TDs value to the array, otherwise add 0. So an example array would look like [5,7,3,0,5,0] - in this case columns 8 and 12 did not contain a TD with class "highlight" and therefore appear as 0 in the array whereas columns 2, 4, 6 and 10 contain such a TD, here with the values 5,7,3,5.

Comment: Add: I think I just need to find a way to check whether one of these columns contains a TD with the class "highlight" or not.

Comment: @user2571510 I think it would be good if you could post example HTML; although, I must add myself that if you use the selector: `td.highlight`, it will only **ever** select those *with* `.highlight`. No needing for any 'checking'.

Comment: Thanks. I added an example table with just one row to show what I mean. Hope that helps. - In this case I would need to check if any of the columns with class "mayContainHighlight" contain a TD with the class "highlight". If yes, add its value to the array, if not add 0.

Comment: @user2571510 Then I hope  this example will illustrate what I'm trying to explain! :) [**http://jsfiddle.net/z2u8m/**](http://jsfiddle.net/z2u8m/) (Notice the jQuery selector)

Comment: Thanks, that's why I thought I can go by columns and check if they contain a TD with class "highlight". Is that not possible ? The columns in question also have a class, if needed.

Comment: Ah!! I see! I apologise - by column and not by cell? I think I see where I'm misunderstanding! x)

Comment: Np, my explanation was probably not the best due missing knowledge. As there can only be 1 or 0 TDs with the class "highlight" in one column I thought this should work.

Comment: @user2571510 Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/adhR6/ I know it's not an array, but I hoping it's along the right lines :)

Comment: Thanks, not exactly. How about we reduce this to just check whether a column contains a TD with the class "highlight" and then return yes or no or 1 or 0 for each of them. Would that work ? I can then handle the rest.

Comment: @user2571510 Then Emanuele Parisio's answer is going to do just that, it checks the class for `.highlight` with a "yes/no" response.

Comment: Yes, this is very close but it does it for every TD so if a column does not contain such a TD it would add 0 for all the TDs in this column whereas I just need one value per column.

Comment: @user2571510 Then you could adjust it so you select by `$('td.mayContainSearchTerm')` which will not select those without data/classes.

Comment: This is it - exactly ! Thanks a lot for spending so much time ! I am going to accept Emanuele's answer as this was the closest but voted all your comments up.